# command line arguments backwards?

Tags: c++

So you all will probably get a chuckle but I am a newbie want to be coder that has a question. Yeah I know probably lame and obvious answer but here it is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  for(int i=argc; i<=argc; i--){
    cout << argv[i] <<endl;
    }

 }
```

Why am I getting a segfault? And when i tweak it I get no output.

Comment: `for(int i=argc; i<=argc; i--)` When will this loop end?

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
for(int i=argc; i<=argc; i--)
```

should be

```
for(int i = argc - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

because

1. Your condition for loop termination was wrong
2. Array indices start from 0 and end at length - 1 (Note: For `argv`, `argv[argc]` is `NULL`)

Change `>=` to `>` if you do not want to include the first argument (the name of the program).

Answer (score 0):

The way the `for` loop has been coded, `i <= argc` will always be `true`. Hence the loop will never end. As soon as `i` is `-1`, you end up accessing memory out of bounds. That is cause for undefined behavior. In your case, the undefined behavior manifests as segmentation fault.

You need to use `i > 0` for the conditional of the `for` statement.

Remember that `argv[0]` is the program name. The arguments to the program start at `argv[1]`.